# Cant return a result from prepared statement

Tags: mysqli

After drifting through various examples of scripts for hours and trying nearly everything I see that is remotely understandable while looking for an answer I am once again at the mercy of the more intelligent. All I want to do is return a name from my database table of users. Is this so hard, seems for me YEP. Someone please set me straight.
I have sorted all errors and now am getting nothing, the problem, I think?, is in the return result statements. Here is my code:

```
<?php
//connect to database
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'fiona', 'imB04', 'Org_db');

// check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
      echo "Connect failed: " . mysqli_connect_errno(); exit();
    }

//Prepared statement, bind and execute 
    if (!$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT `name` FROM users WHERE name = ?" )) {
    echo "Prepare failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
}
//bind parametres
if (!$stmt->bind_param("i", $name)) {
    echo "Binding param failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
//execute query or return error
}
if (!$stmt->execute()) {
    echo "Execute failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
}
//bind result variable
if (!$stmt->bind_result($name)) {
    echo "bind result failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
}
  if ($result = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT `name` FROM users WHERE name = ?")) {
 while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) 
 {
 echo $result['name'];
 }
  }

//Close statement 
      $stmt -> close();
//Close connection 
   $mysqli -> close();  

?>
```

Comment: Well, why don't you get rid of this mess and try the *clean* example from the very **manual page?**

Comment: What I got using the manual example was Name = (NULL) so obviously I just cant get it right

Comment: You need to try manual example anyway. Just because your current cide is *very* inconsistent. Why you're running your query *twice*?

Comment: How do you mean running it twice?

Comment: Well, I mean I see the same query running twice, in the very code you posted. Don't you?

Comment: Stick to the first query, it seems quite all right. but bind $name using "s", not "i"

Answer (score -1):

Try this code,but I think you have gone over the top on your error checking. I could add an else to this select to check for failure. change $db to whatever your database is called.

```
    $query = "SELECT `name` FROM `users` WHERE `name`=?";
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bind_param('s',$name);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($name);

    if($stmt->fetch())
    {
        echo $name;
    }
    $stmt->close();
```

Also for searching for a name I would use this

```
<snip>
"WHERE CONCAT(`firstname`, ' ',`lastname`) LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%')";
$stmt->bind_param('s',$name);
<snip>
```

This is an example of looking for a first and last name. If you use concat it doesn't matter if they have only part of a name, or if they have first name or last name.